# Error .Net Framework when executing app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I developed an app that targets .Net 4.0. Usually I install it in my clients with no problem.
 But today I got an message when executing my app ( after install) that says:

".. the specified service does not exist as an installed service..Exception from HRESULT 0x80070424

The computer run Win7 SP1 ; 64bit
I already unistalled the .Net Framework and installed the 4.5.1 version.
But the problem is still the same !
Any ideias what this could be??

Thanks !

EDIT :: I found the origin of the problem ! I read the Bios Serial Number when I execute the app . I think I ´m not able to do that because when I execute in Ms-dos the command

```
 "wmic bios get serialnumber "
```

I get the same error  "the specified service does not exist as an installed service"...

Comment: I found this: http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/199125-specified-service-does-not-exist.html the second answer - maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the WMI service is installed and running.

Check this link for troubleshooting WMI http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Troubleshooting_WMI